# IOS in-app purchases stopped working suddenly, fetching null identifiers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My in-app purchases were working until yesterday and today I am submitting my app for review. The only change that I made is that in the app page in the iTunes, I connected my app (by checking) with the in-app purchases.

From that time, every time I try in my debug app to buy something with my test account, I am getting this error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'
```

I have already:

1. re-installed my app
2. logged out from my store and used again my test account

but today nothing seems to work. The exact same code was working perfect yesterday, with the same test account.

May it be because I did this change in itunes? I am worrying what would happen when my app gets approved and goes online.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The problem is that the array _products stays nil.

```
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    NSLog(@"reload is called");
    [[VimaIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            NSLog(@"Success from AppStore");
        }
    }];
    for (SKProduct* product in _products) {
        NSLog(@"In-app item:%@",product.localizedTitle);
    }
}
```

The Success log message is never called. Yesterday I had no problem, with the same code.

EDIT:
after a lot of tries, it works. Without changing anything. It seems that the server takes a lot of time to respond back. However, I cannot buy the product since I get an `"cannot connect to itunes"`. Why that might happen?

EDIT2:

In other tries, the problem seems to be in this code:

## pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;
    
    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }
    
    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;
    
}
```

after the for loop. Especially, I get a BAD_ACCESS in line: `_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that during these days the whole Apple Dev Center was down, so the above code is working for anyone else who is looking for an example.

Answer (score 1):

A problem with the Xcode 5 simulator has been reported but not fixed. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542099/in-app-purchase-returns-no-response/18936815) describing the situation.